# Shortest sequence of commands to get `git` into a known state?

Tags: git

Suppose I want to reset a git local repository a.k.a. workspace to a known state (back to the tip of the `develop` branch) regardless of what chaotic state the workspace may be in, including:

- possible uncommitted changes (discard them)
- presence of botched or unfinished merges or rebase
- misconfigured `develop` branch
- currently sitting in a detached HEAD

Can this be accomplished in fewer than 5 commands?

```
git fetch
git checkout -f -B develop
git branch --set-upstream develop origin/develop
git add -A :/
git reset --hard origin/develop
```

Comment: I think your checkout and branch can be merged together as one command: `git checkout --track -fB develop origin/develop`

Comment: While `git reset --hard` aborts an in-progress merge or rebase, I wouldn't want to *count* on this for all possible future versions of Git, if only because "reset --hard aborts things" seems like such a terrible interface. But counting on it simplifies the commands quite a lot, so if you're really going for minimal, well, "go for it" :-) Use @Charlie's suggestion above, and ditch the `git add -A :/` since it just adjusts the index that we're about to reset anyway. Move it up front (or just after `git fetch`) so that `git checkout -fB develop origin/develop` has a clean index.

Comment: The result is just three commands: `git reset --hard`, `git fetch [options]` (in either order); and then `git checkout -fB ...`.

Comment: Removal of the `git add -A :/` causes the `git reset --hard` to not remove everything (it leaves untracked files untouched)

Answer (score 1):

To be a bit pedantic, you can always do this in 2 commands, if you know the origin uri:

```
rm -rf repodir
git clone -b develop git@host:repo/uri repodir
```

Comment: It takes too long on a large repo